# How to write $x=2\cos(3t) y=3\sin(2t)$ in rectangular coordinates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How would I write the following in terms of $x$ and $y$? I think I use the inverse $\cos$ or $\sin$?

$$x=2\cos(3t)\,, \quad y=3\sin(2t)$$

Comment: Are you asking how to eliminate $t$ from the system so as to obtain an equation relating $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, I need to make it in terms of x and y. So I was trying to solve for t in the equation involving x and then plugging that into the equation for y

Comment: Note that the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is not functional...

Answer (score 4):

We have $\cos(3t)=\frac{x}{2}$.  Using the identity $\cos 2u=2\cos^2(u)-1$, we get
$$\cos(6t)=2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2-1.\tag{1}$$

We also have $\sin(2t)=\frac{y}{3}$. Using the not so well-known identity $\sin(3u)=3\sin u-4\sin^3 u$, we get
$$\sin(6t)=3\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)-4\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)^3.\tag{2}$$
Now use (1) and (2), and the fact that $\cos^2(6t)+\sin^2(6t)=1$ to eliminate $t$. 
We get the remarkably ugly equation
$$\left(  2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2-1  \right)^2+\left( 3\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)-4\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)^3 \right)^2=1.$$

Comment: Neat, I just tried my hand at this with another case, $x = 2\cos 3t$, $y= 3\sin 5t$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer (with apologies to Magritte)...

The point is that there is no functional relationship between $x $ and $y$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$ x=2\cos(3t) =  2\cos(2t+t)= 2\cos (2t)\, \cos t - 2 \sin (2t) \,\sin t $$

> $$ \implies x = 2\cos (2t)\, \cos t - 2 \sin (2t) \,\sin t\longrightarrow (*). $$

**Added:** To finish the problem you need to find $\cos(2t),\sin t$, and $\cos t$ in $(*)$. For $\cos (2t)$ we have

$$ \sin(2t)=\frac{y}{3}\implies  \cos (2t) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(2t)}= \sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{9}}. $$

For $\cos t$ and $\sin t$, use the identities

> $$ \cos(2t)=2\cos^2 t-1,\quad \cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2 t. $$

Comment: do I use the inverse cosin? I just don't know how to get rid of the sin and cosine

Comment: How is this a hint?

Comment: @did: it is a very good hint!!

Comment: As can be seen from the OP's comment...

Comment: I don't think it's a very good hint. It forces the OP to solve the problem in the most complicated way possible with questionable steps (like making $\cos(2t)$ to be non-negative).

Comment: This answer does not warrant downvotes: according to my system, this is mathematically correct (i), it is clear and well-written (ii) and it adds value in addressing the question on hand (iii). I wouldn't upvote this, but I wouldn't downvote it either.